# Visual Studio - Whats the difference / benefit to multiple projects vs multiple directories

Tags: visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions

I have a solution currently with a single project and multiple directories.

I was wondering whether there is a benefit to splitting these up into multiple projects instead?

Comment: This is quite a vague question. Could you be more specific? What kind of project is this? Are you planning on exporting it? etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No benefit, not from the description you have provided.

You will only add to the compilation time and deployment complexity.

Each project would end up compiling to a different DLL and the different projects will need to be referenced by each other (I think this is a safe assumption).

If you do need to deploy different portions of your codebase separately, then by all mean, split into multiple assemblies, but don't do it to "organize" your code.

Comment: essentially I was curious if it made compile time faster and organization nicer but it sounds like 1 project is more desirable since I can get the 'organization' idiom via directories/groups under the project.

Comment: @Setheron - More projects with references will make compilation times _slower_.

Answer (score 2):

Single project:

- Fast compile times
- Simplified solution structure along with more control of directory structure
- No circular dependency concerns

Multiple Projects:

- Circular dependencies issues between projects becomes a pain, you have to take more consideration into where you place code (which isn't necessarily a bad thing but when mistakes are made it can cost you a lot of dev time in moving stuff around)
- Slow compile times
- Slower solution loading times
- Not very much control over directory structure
- Finer granularity of control of individual projects settings
- Deployment complexity

Just some off the top of my head

Comment: Why slower compile times? If you change one project the others are not recompiled. So it's faster. And what do you mean by not very much directory structure? And Setheron is talking about solution (sln file) so I also don't understand your comment about distributing anythig as dll's. You add reference from one project to the other and that's all.

Comment: @peri With a few projects you have a point, but I have noticed that when you start reaching 30+ projects like my company that the comparisons seem to take damn near the same amount of time to determine if they should be recompiled or not (especially when the dlls are smaller).

Comment: @peri You make a good point, I corrected the distribution item and substitited it with organization to overcome circular dependency issues.

Answer (score 0):

the question is somewhat vague, but I usually only split things up when they logically fit together and could be used independent of the other code.